# Updating the TEXT attribute on an OpenLayers point

Tags: openlayers, style, modify-features

I have the following map and vector layer declaration that is working:

```
var map;
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  target: "points",
  source: new ol.source.Vector(),
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
      anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
      anchorXUnits: "fraction",
      anchorYUnits: "fraction",
      src: "RedDot.svg",
      }),
            label: "My Junk", 
            text: new ol.style.Text({
                font: '15px Calibri,sans-serif',
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: '#000' }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: '#fff', width: 2
                    }),
                text: "My Truck",
                offsetY: 18,
                })
    })
  });
```

(key info - Note the default `"My Truck"` label for each point)

I have the following function that adds a point to the map (I don't honestly know if it's creating a new layer for each point, or adding all the points to the default layer):

```
function add_map_point(lat, lng, txt) {
  var source = vectorLayer.getSource();
  var pointFeature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([parseFloat(lng), parseFloat(lat)], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
    });
  source.addFeature(pointFeature);
  }
```

This all works - no issues.

What I would like to do is use the TXT variable passed to that function to update the TEXT label ("My Truck" by default).  It seems like I should be able to do something simple like `source.getStyle().setStyle(getText().setText(text: txt));` (over simplified I assume).

Could someone point out how this could be done?

I've been searching all morning, and all I can find is redeclaring the style again, which seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First define a style, with text styling options but no text

```
var style = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
        anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
        anchorXUnits: "fraction",
        anchorYUnits: "fraction",
        src: "RedDot.svg",
    }),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
        font: '15px Calibri,sans-serif',
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: '#000' }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
             color: '#fff', width: 2
        }),
        offsetY: 18,
    })
});
```

Then give your layer a style function which sets the style text from a property of a feature

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    target: "points",
    source: new ol.source.Vector(),
    style: function (feature) {
        style.getText().setText(feature.get('text'));
        return style;
    }
});
```

When you create features include a text property

```
function add_map_point(lat, lng, txt) {
    var source = vectorLayer.getSource();
    var pointFeature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([parseFloat(lng), parseFloat(lat)], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
        text: txt
    });
    source.addFeature(pointFeature);
}
```

Comment: it works!  But I don't understand how it's different - it really just looks like you pulled out the style definition and defined it before assigning it, but without the TEXT declaration.  Unless the getText() function is actually not a static definition when the style is declared, but is a dynamic definition that updates itself when the TEXT feature is added later in the add_map_point function.  Do I have that last part right?

Comment: The important part is setText() in the style function.  The function is called whenever a feature is rendered, and setText() ensures the style returned contains the correct text for that feature.

Comment: Mike, thanks for the clarification - I had no idea (mind blown actually) that you could assign a function as a "value" for a variable in Javascript.  Very cool, and weirdly unsettling at the same time.